# SSL Certificate Working for Domain but not Specific Port

Tags: express, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a domain `sub.example.com` that is configured and fully functioning on an Ubuntu server. I used Certbot to configure the domain with HTTPS, however I also have APIs configured to be accessed on a specific port of that domain, say 2500. When I access `example.com`, I see the lock that says the site is secure, however whenever I go to `example.com:2500/api/someAPI`, the API returns the appropriate result, but without the site being secure. Because the main site is secure, while the API access location isn't, I am unable to make API calls accordingly, resulting in `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

Stack:

1. VPS: Amazon EC2
2. SSL Cert Provider: Let's Encrypt (through Certbot)
3. Server: Node.js (Express)
4. WebApp: React
5. Web Server: nginx

I was able to get it working using the same exact technologies on another VPS (DigitalOcean) and domain some time ago, but I don't believe I ever ran into this issue.

nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
   # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: Certificates do not take into accounts ports, just hostnames. You would need to start by giving full details on the error seen. You can also try with command line clients such as `openssl s_client` or still only at HTTP level with `curl` or `wget`, all of them should give you a clearer picture of the problem (which is probably unrelated to your certificate).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm not sure exactly what you mean, could you elaborate? It seems as though the certificate isn't extending to the specific port, so as you mentioned, it probably isn't the certificate.

Comment: Yes, a given certificate is for a given name, and will work for all ports on that name. If you have a TLS related error it comes from another problem. But the first step would be to show the full error in details, and I gave you some ideas on how to do that.

Comment: Please provide your nginx conf, or at least the relevant parts

Comment: @ofirule I have addedmy nginx.conf file into the op

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue. As it turns out, it has nothing to do with nginx configuration. Rather, in my `node.js`file which defines and exposes the APIs, I needed to include `HTTPS` access. In order to do so, I added the following lines to my code:

```
const https = require('https');

const httpsOptions = {
        cert: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem"),
        key: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/privkey.pem")
}

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(port);
```

Where `<domain>` is replaced by the domain name that the API is hosted on.

Answer (score 0):

By default, no other port than port 443 uses the secure connection. However, if you specify to do so (such as using https://example.com:2500) it should connect securely. If you want it to do this automatically, you need to configure it in the web server application settings. If you know what application is used to host the server (ex. apache) and if you have access to edit the configuration files, you should be able to configure this.

Edit: Sorry, I did not originally see you tagged the question as using nginx. I have not done this specifically before using nginx, but I found [this tutorial](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-ssl-on-nginx/) that explains the process. Inside of /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com, you should be able to change "listen 443 ssl;" to "listen 443, 2500 ssl;" in order to listen on multiple ports. In addition, you would also add `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`in order to redirect connections to an https secure connection (see https://serversforhackers.com/c/redirect-http-to-https-nginx).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am using nginx in as the web server. As I had mentioned, I had done it for another domain, yet cannot remember if I did anything to handle this, do you know what I need to change in order to configure this to work?

Comment: I attempted to do this, however the issue I ran into was that by using the port through nginx, I couldn't run my node server to expose the APIs as well